# I can't download doMC package in R

Tags: r, package, domc

I am doing a group project in which I need the doMC package in R, but when I try to install it it says:

> install.packages(c("DoMC"))
>   WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

```
https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘DoMC’ is not available (for R version 3.6.2)
```

If I try to install Rtools I get the same message. I have the latest version of R.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you put rtool in system path?

Comment: Can you install any packages? You should not need Rtools. Recently, I've gotten the same warning in RStudio, but I have Rtools installed and can build packages from source. But, again, you don't need it since binaries should be available.